# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass after adding an if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an NoMethodError after adding an if statement which throws an error if the number of digits entered by the user is greater than 5.

If the duration filter is not selected and the user searches by another filter without duration it throws the NoMethodError `if @filters[:duration][:durations].join("").length <= 5`

If the duration filter is not selected, i think it would be nil which is throwing the error, I believe?

this is my controller code

```
  unless params[:searched] 
    @filters[:duration] ||= Hash.new
    @filters[:duration][:durations] = ['1']
    @filters[:duration][:operators] = [:gt]
  end

  if @filters.try(:[],:duration).try(:[],:durations)
    @filters[:duration][:durations].map!(&:to_i)
  end

  if @filters[:duration][:durations].join("").length <= 5 

    Notice.gpush("number is within range")
    @recording_metadata = RecordingMetadata.find(@tenant, request.session_options[:id], (start_time..end_time), @filters, additional_options)
  else
    Notice.rpush("4 digits")
    save_notice
    render action: :index
  end
```

Comment: `@filters` is nil or `@filters[:duration]` is nil ? I am not sure how `@filters` can be nil in your disclosed code. Even if `@filters` is not nil there is a chance that `@filters[:duration]` could be nil if your request does not have `searched` param (and you did nothing else in other part of the code).

Comment: `@filters[:duration][:durations]` is nil which is why i think it is throwing the error. if i take out my if statement and do not select duration filter on my page, it works fine and does not throw an error.

Comment: your error message says `undefined method []`, so must be `@filters` is nil or `@filters[:duration]` is nil. You called `[]` method on only `@filters` and `@filters[:duration]`

Comment: What ruby version are you using becuase 2.3 added `Hash#dig` and the safe navigation operator `&.` which is much nicer than how you are trying to traverse that Hash.

Comment: in that case it would be `@filters[:duration]`  that is nil. how would i fix the issue? Ruby version is 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure you have the required keys of a hash, you can use the `fetch` method to provide a fallback.

```
@filters.fetch(:duration, {}).fetch(:durations, []).join("").length <= 5
```

Now if :duration is not present, it will return an empty hash, then the second `fetch` will return an empty array so your code won't throw an exception.